# With standard dot product find all isometries

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{R^3}$ with standatd dot product find all formulas for such isometries:

$f((0,0,1))=(0,1,0)$, $f(af((0,0,0),(0,1,0))) \subset af((0,0,0), (0,0,1))$

I don't know how to solve problems like that

Comment: What does $af$ mean?

Comment: affine combination

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $(0,0,0)$ must be mapped to a multiple of $(0,1,0)$.  We are also given that $f[(0,0,1)] = (0,1,0)$.  Deduce that, since $f$ must be an isometry, there are two valid choices for $f[(0,0,0)]$.  What are they?

In each case, consider the *linear* isometry $\ell(x) = f(x) - f[(0,0,0)]$.  We now know (in each case) exactly what $\ell$ does to $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.  What are the two possibilities for $\ell[(1,0,0)]$?